# Shortcut hotkey is not working after windows update

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-update, shortcuts, hotkeys

I am using a shortcut to mute my sound when I sleep and computer is working, because skype nofitications and so on are annoying during the night.

Before I had a problem that shortcut was activated after some time (3..10 sec), but I fixed it by disabling Superfetch service (afaik it's because of timeout of hanged apps subscribed on keyboard event, and when there are 2-3 apps with 3 sec timeout in queue before our application, we get 6-10 sec delay in execution) and everything worked fine until now.

But after one of last updates (I do not remember which exactly) is stopped to work. I tried to unstuck (<kbd>Win+E</kbd>, <kbd>Win+B</kbd>), but it didn't work. I also tried to move it from desktop to `%programdata%\...\StartMenu`, but without any success.

How can it be fixed?